# Class 'app' not found in bootstrap\app.php:4 #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Logan\Cart\bootstrap\app.php on line 4

Tags: php

I keep getting this error I checked the composer.json file and everything seems to be alright I'm following a tutorial for a shopping cart online in php. Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

I checked a similar question and he corrected in the composer.json file and that's not the issue with my problem.

bootstrap-app.php

```php
<?php

session_start();
$app = new app;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
```

index.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->run();
```

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Cart\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

I've also have dumped the file before and no changes. I'm new to php and I'm just trying to complete this tutorial so I can complete an e-commerce website.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app' not found in
>   C:\Users\Logan\Cart\bootstrap\app.php:4 Stack trace: #0   C:\Users\Logan\Cart\public\index.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Logan\Cart\bootstrap\app.php on line 4

Edited to include this:

```
<?php

namespace Cart;

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DIBridge;


class App extends DIBridge
{
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder)
    {
        $builder->addDefintions (
            ['settings.displayErrorDetails' => true,] );

            $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ .'/container.php');
    }   

}
```

Comment: Where is the "app" class declared?

Comment: In app.php correct?

Comment: You may want to start with something a little more basic than completing an e-commerce website. You should start by getting an understanding of classes and namespacing.

Comment: Here it is: ```<?php

namespace Cart;

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DIBridge;


class App extends DIBridge
{
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder)
    {
        $builder->addDefintions (
            ['settings.displayErrorDetails' => true,] );

            $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ .'/container.php');
    }   

}```

Comment: @lebaneseblonde252 In that case, your class is actually `Cart\App`. Not just `App`, and not `app` either.

Comment: So let me get this right in my json file I should have "Cart\\": "Cart\App/"